# Como sacar un valor de un if en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

actualmente estoy trabajando en una pagina web con HTML y JS. Estoy creando un botón que se active cuando un audio finaliza, para esto, estoy usando una variable general "myAudio", dependiendo del index en el que este el slider, a myAudio se le asigna un audio diferente, por cierto, myAudio tiene un valor por defecto, que es el primer audio.

Codifique el botón fuera de los if, este es el código:

```
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');

myAudio.onplay = () => {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
myAudio.onended = () => {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
$('.next').on('click', function(){
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    myAudio.play();
});
```

Este el código del los IF:

```
function sliderTimeout(index) {
    // Establecer índice actual
    owl.currentIndex = index;
    // Eliminar temporizador actual
    clearTimeout(owlTimer);
    // Obtener elemento actual por índice, jQuery inicia con cero, por eso el -1
    // Solo si no es el último elemento
    if(index < imgItems) {
        // Definir tiempo por defecto para todos los elementos
        let time = 000;
        // Aquí puedes analizar el contenido del elemento actual
        // Para elegir audio y duración, cambiando el tiempo de espera
        // Por ejemplo: dar el doble de tiempo para el segundo elemento
        if(index == 1) {
            myAudio.play();
            time = 100000;
            //Objeto con referencia a la etiqueta audio     
            myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            document.getElementById("myAudio").play();  
            document.getElementById("myAudio").currentTime = 0;
            document.getElementById("myAudio2").pause();
        }
        if(index == 2) {
            time = 200000;
            //Objeto con referencia a la etiqueta audio    
            myAudio.currentTime = 0; 
            myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio2");
            document.getElementById("myAudio").pause();
            document.getElementById("myAudio2").currentTime = 0;
            document.getElementById("myAudio3").pause();
            myAudio.play();
        }
```

Como vieron anteriormente, myAudio cambia constantemente dependiendo del index o la posición del slider, pero, el botón no obtiene esos valores que cambian, si no que se va por el valor por defecto, hay alguna manera para retornar el valor que da el IF actual?

Comment: Deberías comprobar que a `sliderTimeout` llega el `index` que crees que llega. Si no es asi es que hay algo asíncrono en `owl.trigger`. Si asi fuera, deberías ver si  `owl.trigger` tiene callback y quizá lo deberías usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas el código de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/464712/54039) a una de tus preguntas anteriores, no deberías tener problema para que tus sliders avancen cuando termine el audio y no necesitas otros eventos para ocultar o mostrar botones, lo haces directamente en la función que controla el avance.

Te dejo este fragmento de código (sin Owl Carousel ni jQuery), pero con la misma lógica sugerida en la respuesta anterior para que veas que funciona correctamente; agregué solamente la parte para desactivar botones, ya depende de ti (o del tipo de botones que estés usando) si quieres modificar estilos o solo el atributo `disabled`.

```js
let sliders, audio, anterior, siguiente;

function audioFin(e) {
    // Obtener índice desde audio que disparó el evento
    let index = +e.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    avanzar(index + 1);
}

function avanzar(index) {
    // Por defecto, los dos botones activados
    anterior.disabled = false;
    siguiente.disabled = false;
    
    // Verificar límites
    if(!index || index <= 1) {
        // Aquí debes desactivar el botón "Anterior"
        anterior.disabled = true;
        index = 1;
    }
    if(index >= sliders.length) {
        // Aquí debes desactivar el botón siguiente
        siguiente.disabled = true;
        index = sliders.length;
    }
    if(audio) {
        // Si hay audio, detener reproducción, cancelar evento y eliminar
        audio.pause();
        audio.removeEventListener('ended', audioFin);
        audio = null;
    }
    // Ocultar todos los elementos (eso lo debe hacer Owl Carousel)
    sliders.forEach(slider => slider.classList.remove('show'));
    // Mostrar elemento actual
    sliders[index - 1].classList.add('show');
    // Buscar audio
    audio = document.querySelector('#audio' + index);
    // ¿Hay audio?
    if(audio) {
        // Asignar índice en atributo de datos
        audio.dataset.index = index;
        // ajustar tiempo al inicio y reproducir
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
        audio.addEventListener('ended', audioFin);
    } else {
        // No hay audio, ¿deberías usar setTimeout?
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
    anterior = document.querySelector('#anterior');
    siguiente = document.querySelector('#siguiente');
    avanzar();
});
```

```css
.slider {
    opacity:0;
    max-height:0;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
.slider.show {
    opacity:1;
    max-height:80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <p>Texto de elemento 1</p>
    <audio id="audio1" src="https://www.kozco.com/tech/LRMonoPhase4.mp3" controls=""></audio>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <p>Texto de elemento 2</p>
    <audio id="audio2" src="https://www.kozco.com/tech/piano2-CoolEdit.mp3" controls=""></audio>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <p>Texto de elemento 3</p>
    <audio id="audio3" src="https://www.kozco.com/tech/organfinale.mp3" controls=""></audio>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <p>Texto de elemento 4, sin audio</p>
</div>
<button id="anterior">&lt;</button>
<button id="siguiente">&gt;</button>
```

**Notas:**

- Como ves, no puede haber más de un audio en reproducción al mismo tiempo, eso es lo bueno de que uses la misma variable para todos.
- No agregué evento a los botones Anterior y Siguiente, porque eso lo debe controlar Owl Carousel.

**Recomendación:** En la medida de lo posible, evita mezclar instrucciones de jQuery con Javascript puro, porque puede llevarte a confusiones y complica el mantenimiento de tus códigos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, siempre eres de mucha ayuda!

Comment: Ya termine mi pagina web, la voy a publicar en internet, por si te gustaría darle un vistazo.

Comment: ¡@AlexanderCoronado, por supuesto que me gustaría verla!